# Why are these files not being loaded in the product page of Magento? (M1.9.3.8)

Tags: local.xml, magento-1.9.3.8

Does anyone know why this is not being rendered (saved in the local.xml of my custom theme)?

The location of the local.xml is `app/design/frontend/mobile/XX/layout/local.xml`

and the content is

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="body">
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

The location of the js files is `./js/varien/`

Thanks for your tips on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Changed `<reference name="body">` to `<reference name="head">` :)

Comment: Accept your answer.

Comment: I cannot accept my answer in two days

Comment: Yes and you can do after two days.